# Disable default pagination in react table without affecting the default sorting function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table, react-table-v6

So I have a react table that renders data from serverside with pagination enabled. Initially, I has the `manual` attribute set to `false` which makes react auto generate the pagination data. At this point, the sorting was okay too. As that would not work well for me as I depended on server side pagination, I had to turn the `manual` attribute to `true` to turn off the auto generated gagination data which now causes the default sort function to go away as well. Please is there a way to keep the sorting and just turn off the auto pagination in react table. Thanks.

Table component returns this currently:

```
            <ReactTable
                columns={columns}
                data={data}
                pageSize={data.length}
                defaultSorted={sort}
                getTrProps={getTrProps}
                manual={true}
                {...paginationData} // custom pagination data
            />
```

Comment: Are you sure that's meeting requirements? Because it would paginate from the server, but the grid would only sort the paged result set, not the whole set. You need to handle sorting on the server too if you do paging there.